# React app on Docker node_modules folder not available

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

maybe i am stupid, but i watched a tutorial on how to run a react application on a docker container.

I created the Dockerfile:

```yaml
FROM node:18.13.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . . 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Then i created the image and runed the container

```
docker build -t frontend-image
docker run -d --name frontend-container frontend-image
```

When running the Docker i getting a lot of the following errors:

```
2023-03-30 17:02:05 ERROR in ./src/App.js 1:40-93
2023-03-30 17:02:05 Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
2023-03-30 17:02:05 You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

The node_modules folder got created and in this case the react-refresh package is in the node_modules folder.

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file that excludes the host's `node_modules` directory from the image build?  I could see something like this happening if the `COPY` step accidentally overwrites the `RUN npm install` step.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, i have an .dockerignore file with the node_modules directory in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got a solution on another forum, but i want to share it here.
The Problem was, that I used storybook what led to multiple versions of react-refresh.

The solution was to add this to the package.json:

```
"overrides": {
  "react-refresh": "0.11.0"
}
```

So only one version of react-refresh is installed